# Alfresco search by xpath in the javascript console

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I've trouble starting to learn how to perform queries in alfresco xpath.
I'm working in the alfresco javascript console as a prototipization and for proof of concept.

The final goal is to find all children of a node of a certain type (in my case, 'doc:doc'), or, as an alternative, I'd like to exclude the thumbnails (renditions).

assuming that the node is called "node", I already tried the following:
`node.childrenByXPath('*//.') //the search works, but no filter on type` 
... but none of these works
`node.childrenByXPath("*//[@type='doc:doc']") node.childrenByXPath("*//.[TYPE='doc:doc']") node.childrenByXPath("TYPE='doc:doc'") node.childrenByXPath("+TYPE='doc:doc'")`

Can anyone help or at least point me a good tutorial on this topic?
i've followed https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-hub/search-documentation/ba-p/289935 but there are no examples on how to specify the type of a node

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

childrenByXPath only filters on the PATH (check node browser for the "Primary Path" on a node to see how a qname path looks like). There is no Type on the qname path.

You may want to use the search API instead:

```js
var def =
{
query: "PATH:'"+ node.qnamePath +"/*' AND TYPE:'doc:doc' AND !TYPE:'cm:thumbnail'",
language: "fts-alfresco"
};
var results = search.query(def);
print(results);
```

Comment: Thank you, works like I intended